# Creating new model with association but without parent instance

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have these model.

```
var User = this.sequelize.define('user', {name: String})
var Account = this.sequelize.define('account', {account: String})

User.hasMany(Account);
Account.belongsTo(User);
```

Now, assume that in TABLE `User`, i already have:

```
| id | name   |
|----|--------|
| 1  | Maat   |
| 2  | MatieL |
```

Now, i want to create an account but i only want to use User ID not user instance.

```
Account.create({name: 'MyAccount', userid: 1});
```

But after that, the row show in TABLE `Account` is:

```
| id |   account   |userId|
|----|-------------|------|
| 1  | MyAccount   | NULL |
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. Please suggest me if you know the answer. 
Thank you.

PS:
I know that i can create account instance by another way by firstly finding `userinstance` by userid then after create `account` then call `userinstance.addAccount(account)`, but i don't want to use that way because it cost more queries.

PS2: The solution is userId with i capital, not userid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi The default foregin key is user_id and not userid

Refer http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/docs/associations/#foreign-keys

Comment: Thank you, but in my way, i don't know why but it is userId with "I" capital :D